# Why my code is not working at Code Chef, although its working well in my local machine

Tags: python-3.x

Problem URL: https://www.codechef.com/JUNE20B/problems/XYSTR

Chef and String Problem Code: XYSTR

It passes all the shown test cases but still not working.

```
for _ in range(int(input())):
    string = str(input())
    substring = 'xy'
    count = string.count(substring)
    print(count)
```

Comment: What exactly does "it is not working" mean?

Comment: would this be a networking or dev ops issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are not counting 'yx'. Going by your code, `yxyx` will only yield 1, but correct answer would be 2.